# obj export in MaxfilePath

Tags: maxscript

I can't english well:(
I made funtions FBX Exporter and OBJ Exporter.

```
fn FBXexport =
(
    local MaxSave = getFilenamePath maxfilename + "\\" + getFilenameFile maxfilename + ".fbx"
    local plug = findItem exporterPlugin.classes FBXEXP

   exportFile MaxSave #noPrompt selectedOnly: (selection.count != 0 ) using: plug
)
```

```
fn OBJexport =
(
    local MaxSave = getFilenamePath maxfilename + "\\" + getFilenameFile maxfilename + ".obj"
    local plug = findItem exporterPlugin.classes ObjExp

    exportFile MaxSave #noPrompt selectedOnly: (selection.count != 0 ) using: plug
)
```

it is same code to getFilenamePath.

FBX Exporter is success to MaxfilePath\MaxfileName.fbx
**but OBJ Exporter made OBJ, Maxfile in Drive\MaxfileName.obj ( E:\Maxfilename.obj )**

I don't know why :(
I want to make obj in maxfilePath

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

```
fn OBJexport = 
    (
        local MaxSave = getFilenamePath maxfilepath + "\\" + getFilenameFile maxfilename + ".obj"
        local plug = findItem exporterPlugin.classes ObjExp

        exportFile MaxSave #noPrompt selectedOnly: (selection.count != 0 ) using: plug
    )
```